# Instance method 'onReceive(_:perform:)' requires that 'CountdownTimer' conform to 'Publisher'

Tags: swiftui

I'm currently building out a project where a user could create multiple timers however I'm running into the following error. "Instance method 'onReceive(_:perform:)' requires that 'CountdownTimer' conform to 'Publisher'". I just can't figure out how to get Countdown Timer to conform to Publisher.

Here is the code for my timer object:

```
struct CountdownTimer: Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  let name: String
  var minutes: Int
  var seconds: Int

  var countdown: Int  {
    let totalTime = seconds + (minutes * 60)
        return totalTime
  }
} 

func timeString(time: Int) -> String {
    return String(format: "%01i:%02i", minutes, seconds)

}
  

class CountdownTimers: ObservableObject {
  @Published var timers = [CountdownTimer]()
}
```

My Content View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
@ObservedObject var countdownTimers = CountdownTimers()

@State private var showingAddSheet = false


let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Color.pastelGreen
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                VStack {
                    ScrollView {
                        ForEach(countdownTimers.timers) { timer in
                            ZStack {
                                CardView()
                                    .overlay(
                                        HStack {
                                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                                Text("\(timer.countdown)")
                                                    .font(.custom("Quicksand-Bold", size: 30))
                                                Text(" \(timer.timeString(time: timer.countdown))")
                                                    .font(.custom("Quicksand-Bold", size: 40))
                                                    .onReceive(timer){ _ in
                                                        if timers.countdown > 0 {
                                                            timers.countdown -= 1
                                                        }
                                                    }
```

The error is happening on the .OnReceive(timer) line. the minutes and seconds are created on a different "AddView" but I don't believe that the issue is related to that section.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're shadowing the name `timer`. It appears first here:

```
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
```

Then, later, you use it again here:

```
ForEach(countdownTimers.timers) { timer in
```

Swift is going to assume you always mean the `timer` in the most-recently-defined scope, so when you use `.onReceive`, it assumes you mean `timer` from the `ForEach` (which is of type `CountdownTimer`) and not the `Timer` defined earlier.

To fix this, use a *different name* in your `ForEach` and adjust your code (such as the `Text` elements) to use the new name.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! However I'm running into this error on the -= line. "Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'countdown' is a get-only property"

Comment: Yes, that's a separate issue -- you need a binding to your `timer` (let's call it `timerItem` now) in your `ForEach`. You can likely do `ForEach($countdownTimers.timers) { $timerItem`, but it may need some adjustment (start a new question to address the new issue if so). You can read more about that here: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/bindable-swiftui-list-elements/